# Recognizing language type arguments in function calls

Tags: r, primitive

I want to create an overloaded function that behaves differently given the arguments provided. For this, I need to check if the argument given is an existing object (e.g. data frame, list, integer) or an abstract formula (e.g. `a + b`, `2 * 4`, `y ~ x + y` etc.). Below I paste what I would like it to recognize:

```
df <- data.frame(a, b)

f(df) # data.frame
f(data.frame(a, b)) # data frame
f(a + b) # expression
f("a + b") # character
f(2 * 2 + 7) # expression
f(I(2 * 2)) # integer
```

Is it possible to construct such a function? How? Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any references on the web or in the books on R programming I know.

The general way of overloading functions in R would be something like this:

```
f <- function(x) UseMethod("f")
f.default <- function(x) eval(substitute(x)) 
f.data.frame <- function(x) print("data frame")
```

It gives:

```
> f(df)
[1] "data frame"
> f(2 + 2)
[1] 4
> f(list(a, b))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

So the problem with doing it like this is that I would have to name all the possible **other** data types rather than checking if `x` is an expression.

The same is with using:

```
f2 <- function(x) typeof(substitute(x))
```

because it evaluates function calls and expressions in the same manner:

```
> f2(2 + 2)
[1] "language"
> f2(df)
[1] "symbol"
> f2(data.frame(a, b))
[1] "language"
```

while I would like it to differentiate between `list(a, b)` and `2 + 2`, because the first one is a list, and the second one is an expression.

I know that it would be easy with a classic R formula that is easily recognizable by R, but is it possible with different input?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `?UseMethod`

Comment: I tried, but defining `f.default <- function(x) eval(substitute(x))` or something similar gives an effect that everything is evaluated as 'default' (I'll update mu question on that).

Comment: What about `f.expression <- function(x) print("expression")` ?

Comment: it returns an error because it evaluates the expression and then checks the type so `f(2 + 2)` is a `double` or `numeric` rather than `expression` or "object not found" error in `f(a + b)` is there's no `a` and `b` variables in the environment.

Comment: `a+b` is not an expression object.  `expression(a+b)` is.

Answer (score 1):

It is the principle of object oriented langage in R. You should learn a bit more about it here:

https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~stat782/downloads/08-Objects.pdf
http://brainimaging.waisman.wisc.edu/~perlman/R/A1%20Introduction%20to%20object-oriented%20programming.pdf

There are two types of objects in R: S3 and S4. S3 objects are easier to implement and more flexible. Their use is sufficient for what you want to do. You can use **S3 generic functions**.

I strongly advise you to learn more about these S3 and S4 classes, but to make it short, you can just look at the `class` of parameter you give to function `f`. This can be done thanks to function `class`.

You can separate your function `f` in different cases:

```
f <- function(a){
   if (class(a) == 'data.frame'){
     # do things...
   }
   else if (class(a) == 'formula'){
     # do things...
   }
   else if (class(a) == 'integer'){
     # do things...
   }
   else {
     stop("Class no supported")
   }

}
```

Comment: `class(2 + 2)` is `numeric`, the same as `class(4)`, while I want to recognize that in the first case it is an expression. The same with `class(substitute(2 + 2))` and `class(substitute(list(a, b)))` both return `call` class while I would like them to differentiate between expression and an object.

Comment: @Tim How is R supposed to know that you consider `2 + 2` an expression, but `list(a, b)` not? Both `+` and `list` are functions that return a valid object. If you want to differentiate between them you need to tell R explicitly, which functions you want to have evaluated and which not.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems I tried to complicate it in a greater extent than I had to. The simple answer is just:

```
if (tryCatch(is.data.frame(x), error=function(z) FALSE)) {
   # here do stuff with a data.frame
} else {
   # here check the expression using some regular expressions etc.
}
```